# Fatal Error: Bad Primary Partition 0: Partition ends in the final partial cylinder, press any key to exit cfdisk

Tags: android, android-x86

to fix this issue, i follow these steps

1，after “Warning!! Unsupported GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected. Use GNU Parted” , press alt+F2

2，command shell：

```
parted /dev/sda
mklabel msdos
yes
quit
```

3，reboot，and you can install android-x86 with offical method

Comment: thanks bro, you help my days